# Problem with deprecated auto_ptr when installing cpptest on 18.04

Tags: gcc, c++

I am trying to install cpptest from https://sourceforge.net/projects/cpptest/ and I am getting compile errors.

A sample error is:

```
g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../config      -g -O2 -MT mytest.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/mytest.Tpo -c -o mytest.o mytest.cpp
In file included from ../src/cpptest.h:34:0,
                 from mytest.cpp:39:
../src/cpptest-suite.h:58:17: warning: ‘template<class> class std::auto_ptr’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   void add(std::auto_ptr<Suite> suite);
                 ^~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/memory:80:0,
                 from ../src/cpptest-suite.h:33,
                 from ../src/cpptest.h:34,
                 from mytest.cpp:39:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/unique_ptr.h:51:28: note: declared here
   template<typename> class auto_ptr;
```

Looking at /usr/include/c++/7/bits/unique_ptr.h:51, I see:

```
 #if _GLIBCXX_USE_DEPRECATED
   template<typename> class auto_ptr;
 #endif
```

There doesn't seem to be any way to turn off _GLIBCXX_USE_DEPRECATED.  If so, this seems to conflict with the default to report the error.

What is the proper thing to do at this point?

Comment: Those appear to be warnings - not errors. Regardless, it looks like the project moved to github several years ago: https://github.com/cpptest/cpptest

Comment: The gitub release has an open issue (#1) about completing the migration to github.doesn't have the configure file referenced in the INSTALL document

Comment: ... you create the configure script by running the provided autogen script, `./autogen.sh`

Comment: @steeldriver.  Thanks.  I wasn't aware of that.  I was trying to use the raw autoconf.

Comment: @steeldriver  And still getting the same errors.  I will need to look at the cpptest code some more.  Probably need to change some code there.

Answer (score 0):

The messages are warnings, not errors.

They can be suppressed by passing the `-Wno-deprecated` compilation flag:

> ```
>    -Wno-deprecated
>        Do not warn about usage of deprecated features.
> ```

ex.

```
./configure CXXFLAGS=-Wno-deprecated
make
```

---

Alternatively, you can install and use an older version of the compiler which doesn't deprecate these code features

```
./configure CC=/usr/bin/gcc-5 CXX=/usr/bin/g++-5
```

Comment: Yes!  Turning off the warning did it.